# Google Autocomplete Not Working Inside Foundation Accordion

Tags: php, google-maps, autocomplete, accordion

I can't seem to get Google autocomplete to work inside a Foundation accordion (in WordPress).  The code works fine outside the accordion.  (It should be noted that there are three inputs where the same autocomplete is in place - the other two are also working fine.)

- At first, I thought maybe it was an event delegation issue since the accordion is off canvas to begin with (mobile view only).  But changing the code to account for that doesn't seem to have helped.
- Then I Googled around and saw where maybe I needed to adjust the z-index, but that doesn't seem to have helped either.

Here's what I've got inside my JavaScript file:

```
    jQuery('body').on('input change', '.autocomplete', function () {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this);
        autocomplete.inputId = this.id;
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
            const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        });
        //jQuery('.pac-container').css({'z-index': '9999', 'display': 'block'});
    });
```

And here's what the relevant portion of my HTML looks like:

```
    <a href="#" class="accordion-title">City</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
            <div class="cell small-12">
                <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x">
                    <label for="filter-address-mobile" class="text-right middle">Choose a Location:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="filter-address-mobile" class="filter-address autocomplete" name="filter-address" value="<?php echo $search_filters->address ?>" placeholder="Enter Address">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="text-right">
            <button class="button small">Apply</button>
        </footer>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  The autocomplete dropdown was there the whole time.  I just needed to up my z-index beyond the 99999 suggestion I came across in a different thread.  Because the autocomplete was inside a Foundation accordion, mine seems to have needed a z-index of 9999999.